# How do I declare and use a global 2d array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, global-variables

I tried declaring the array in the h file as:
int arr[32][32];
but I found that my program's functions could not change the values of the array. What is the correct way to go about this? Thanks for your time.

Comment: then it might very well be a problem with your functions. show us what you got there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem must be somewhere else. You can most definitely define an `int arr[32][32]` array. Here's a working example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int arr[32][32];

int main() {
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
      arr[i][j] = i + j;
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
      printf("[%d,%d] = %d\n", i, j, arr[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I found the actual problem, thanks for this!